# Type loading by Assembly.LoadFrom is not the same

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection

I'm creating type by name to put them to DI container. For any reason the DI container fails to register/resolve types created this way:

```
Type interfaceTypeFromAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(InterfacesAssemblyPath).GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == interfaceName);
Type implementorTypeFromAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(ApplicationAssemblyPath).GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == implementorClassName);
```

I compared types and found that:

```
Type implClassType= typeof(ImplClass);
Type implClassType2= typeof(ImplClass);
bool res = implClassType == implClassType2; // True

res = implClassType == implementorTypeFromAssembly; // False
```

The last line gives False although types have the same GUID.

What's the reason of such a behavior?

Comment: What is the value of implementorTypeFromAssembly.ToString() ?

Comment: @ShaiAharoni toString() for both objects give the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types are different because `typeof(ImplClass)` loads type from assembly that is already loaded in app domain and `Assembly.LoadFrom(InterfacesAssemblyPath)` loads the assembly again. This means the Assembly object instance returned from `Assembly.LoadFrom` is new including new instances of all types.

There is no reason to use `Assembly.LoadFrom` when the assembly is already loaded in app domain. In this case you should acquire `Assembly` object from app domain. For example via `Assembly.GetAssembly(SomeTypeInAssembly)` or `typeof(SomeTypeInAssembly).Assembly`.

**EDIT:**

If you do not have any `SomeTypeInAssembly` or you do not want to use it you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Single(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == name)`.

Comment: Ok, but all that I have is class name, which is string. Should I do something like _Type.GetType("ClassNameFromAssembly")_ and then pass is to GetAssembly?

Comment: If you want to get `Assembly` object by name, you can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Single(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == name)`

Comment: Thank you. Now it works!
_Assembly assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == "ServerApp.UnitTests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
Type typeFromAssembly = assembly.GetType("ServerApp.UnitTests.MyType");_
But I'm still wondering why
_var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(Type.GetType("ServerApp.UnitTests.MyType"));_
doesn't work?